# What library should I use to create costume chart in react native?

Tags: react-native, d3.js, chart.js

Hey I have an app in react native and I want to add a chart like in this image:

[image]

With what library would you recommend to me to use?

Comment: Please see the SO help guide on [what types of questions should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Questions asking for recommendations for libraries are better directed to somewhere like reddit, React user forums, or other venues that welcome discussion.

Answer (score 1):

I used react-native pure charts.

Installation via npm:

```
npm install react-native-pure-chart --save
```

Usage example for line chart:

`render(
...
let sampleData = [30, 200, 170, 250, 10]
 <PureChart data ={sampleData} type='line' />
...
);`

Further information:
https://reactnativeexample.com/react-native-chart-library-that-only-using-react-native-pure-components/ , 
  https://github.com/oksktank/react-native-pure-chart

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where can I see more example to know which one I should use for my example below? Because I can’t see something that looks like what I want

Comment: Currently only the types line, bar and pie are available. For types like your example you will maye have to import a drawing library and use another package.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using Chart.js, It is very easy to get started and understand. Almost every type of chart is supported, and you get full fledge option to customize things with tons of plugins availaible.

For the need of yours, I think this Horizontal bar of chart.js would be worth a look -> http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/horizontal.html

Comment: thank you for the answer... how can I make the faded color that complete to 100%?